# Divs and content of divs are overlapped when using position absolute to a div in web view

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I created a design. in that three images inside a parent div are stacked to each other with position absolute. when i created a mobile responsive view for that design the image's div vanished and the other div overlapped it. the images inside that div overlapped other divs. how can i create a responsive design while using position absolute in web view?

i tried everything for the above mentioned problem but nothing happened

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put relevant code into your question. The phrase “ are stacked to each other with position absolute” is bit worrying because once an element is position absolute it is removed from the flow and doesn’t influence others positions.